# How to unmerge edit and remove buttons in sugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

When in SugarCRM CE when I insert an edit button into a custom sub panel meta file for some reason it merges it with the "remove" button as per attach. So the edit button gets a dropdown arrow and 'remove' button appears when we click on the arrow.

The code I use to show the buttons is

```
    // Edit button
    'edit_button'=>array(
        'widget_class' => 'SubPanelEditUsersprjct_projectsButton',
        'projects_users_id'=>'projects_users_id',
        'module' => 'Users',
        'width' => '5%',
    ),
    'remove_button'=>array(
        'vname' => 'LBL_REMOVE',
        'widget_class' => 'SubPanelRemoveButton',
        'module' => 'Users',
        'width' => '4%',
        'linked_field' => 'users',
    ),
```

How do I get the 2 buttons to show up next to each other.

Exact same issue as described here: http://wiki-crm-forum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9632&p=33429&sid=e82d1abbf9f4d0b39f01137dd9e4c913#p33429 but there's no solution it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem but I have a workaround.

You may remove "Remove" from subpanels and use this free plugin to add "Remove" button in subpanel in front of each row.

https://store.outrightcrm.com/product/outright-listview-delete/